# modify line in a .txt file in bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I have a .txt that contains lines and these in turn data separated by "," for example:

```
10,05,nov,2016,122,2,2,330,user
```

What I want is to be able to modify a parameter of an X line, which the search method is the first number, which is unique, is not repeated.
For example find the number 10 (f1) and modify the row containing the 122 (f5).
I've tried it with `sed` but I can't do it.
I've commented that with `awk` I could, but I did'nt study that command.
Some help??

Comment: Please add your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

A simple awk script like the following should do the trick :

```
awk -v find="10" -v field="5" -v newval="abcd" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {if ($1 == find) $field=newval; print $0}' test.csv
```

Explanation:

- `awk -v find="10" -v field="5" -v newval="abcd"` : defines 3 variables for awk. `find`, that contains the pattern we are looking for,`field` that contains the number of the field we want to edit, and `newval` with the value to replace.
- `BEGIN {FS=OFS=","}` : before iterating through the file, we set the File Separator and Output File Separator to ",".
- `if ($1 == find) $field=newval`: if the 1rst field of a line contains the pattern we want, we set the Nth field (1st if `$field=1`, 2nd if `$field=2`, ...) to the value of `newval`
- `print $0`: whatever the result from the if test, we print the whole line.

A shorter (but less understandable) version of this script could be written as follow :

```
awk -v a="10" -v f="5" -v n="abcd" -F, '$1 == a {$f=n}OFS=FS' test.csv
```

Where `a` refers to `find`, `f` refers to `field`, `n` refers to `newval` and `-F,` refers to `FS=","`

Script in action :

```
> cat test.csv
11,05,nov,2016,122,2,2,330,user
10,05,nov,2016,123,2,2,330,user
12,05,nov,2016,124,2,2,330,user

> awk -v find="10" -v field="5" -v newval="abcd" 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=","} {if ($1 == find) $field=newval; print $0}' test.csv
11,05,nov,2016,122,2,2,330,user
10,05,nov,2016,abcd,2,2,330,user
12,05,nov,2016,124,2,2,330,user
```

Answer (score 0):

With sed:

```
$ sed '/^10/s/,[^,]*/,333/4' <<< "10,05,nov,2016,122,2,2,330,user"
10,05,nov,2016,333,2,2,330,user
```

In lines starting with `10`, search for 4th comma followed by non-comma characters and replace with your substitution string.