# How to replace other column-entries when searching for a specific column in a file?

Tags: awk, grep, text-processing

Suppose my file looks like this:

```
A   1   0  
B   1   0  
C   1   0
```

How can I search for the line that has B in the first column, and if so, switch the entries in the second and third column? So my final result would look like:

```
A   1   0  
B   0   1  
C   1   0
```

Comment: What is the delimiter? One whitespace or one tab?

Comment: This is a good question in that the problem is clearly explained. To make it an even better question, that more people will be interested in helping with, add some research or show your attempts to solve the problem and where you are getting stuck.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [modify line in a .txt file in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40633311/modify-line-in-a-txt-file-in-bash)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -

```
vipin@kali:~$ awk '{if($1 == "B") {print $1,$3,$2} else print $1,$2,$3}'  kk
A 1 0
B 0 1
C 1 0
```